# Points coordinates in multiple screen CoronaSDK

Tags: coronasdk

I'm new to Corona SDK development and I'm looking around to get some documentations and see if this platform is goot to reach my goal.

Let's say that I have a background image in my screen (320X480 for example), and I want to move an object from one point to another. For example I want to move an object from 100,100 to 300,300. In this case, my object follow a line that almost covers the entire width of my screen. But what happens when I run the app on a different screen resolution? For example on a Ful HD screen, moving an object from 100 to 300 on the X axis, it just moves a little.

What I saw from Corona documentations is that multiple screen is supported by providing different image resolutions. But what happens when I have to go through screen coordinates? Do I have to check at runtime for the screen resolution and do all the Math operations to scale my points coordinates? Or is there anything else that I'm missing?

I ask you sorry if I missed something from the doc :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually corona will do all such work for you, if you have added proper `config.lua` to your project. But I'm doing it in a different way for more precision and for my satisfaction:

**In normal case:**

```
-- Your object at point (100,100)
local myObject = display.newRect(0,0,50,50)
myObject.x = 100
myObject.y = 100

-- sample transition 
transition.to(myObject,{time=1000,x=300,y=300})
```

**What I'm doing:**

```
-- Create a scale factor for X and Y
local _x = display.contentWidth/320
local _y = display.contentHeight/480

-- Multiply X values with '_x' and Y values with '_y', as below:
local myObject = display.newRect(0,0,50*_x,50*_y)
myObject.x = 100*_x
myObject.y = 100*_y

transition.to(myObject,{time=1000,x=300*_x,y=300*_y})
```

**Note:**

- While trying the above code, you have to develop your code for iPhone simulator. Hence, I obtained `local _x = display.contentWidth/320`, where the division factor is the `width` of the simulator/screen that you are using to build your app. And in local `_y = display.contentHeight/480`, the division factor is the `height` of the simulator/screen.

Keep Coding................. :)

Comment: Perfect. That it's what I wanted to do. You said: Usually corona will do all such work for you, if you have added proper config.lua. What's the correct option for this? Or do I have to multiply for screen scale factor every coordinates of my point?

Comment: While adding config.lua to your project, usually your app will adjust for every allowable screen resolutions. But I've found some mismatching in certain cases. So I'm generally using my own method as I specified above... :)
If you want to know more about 'config.lua', visit: http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/

Comment: I already figured it out. Infact the "Important Notes" chapter clearly explains that point coordinates will not scale down/up for different screen resolution. I think I will go for the coding solution. Always the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

It scales it all for you.  I'm not sure if it specifically mentions it in the documentation, probably.

I am also newer to Corona (since July) with no previous mobile experience.  It has blown me away with what it can do.

Comment: I thought this too. But I saw this: http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/ Check the Important Notes chapter

Comment: Yeah I've seen that before.  I think it's mainly concerning aspect ratios (I use the letterbox sizing function).  But I did something weird on my app and there isn't any letterbox, which is nice.  This might be a case of the blind leading the blind.

Comment: I think that I will only get it by trying. I though that this was a main feature and would have been written somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Corona does all the work for you. You define your default screen resolution (320x480 for example) and in whatever resolution you want to move from 100 to 300 it will behave equally because corona will treat all screens resolutions as it was 320x480.

Comment: I thought this too. But why in this article is written something different? http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/

Comment: It does not say something different. You have to do all this to support screen with different aspect ratio. You don't have to do all the things the article say. But if you don't and you insert an image at the point (0,0) it will be different in some devices, because you defined that you screen is 320x480 and you are using a device with 640x480, the (0,0) will not be at the edge of the screen. It's not very easy to explain but I work with corona for a long time and I think it's the easiest SDK to support multiple screens. You can download corona for free, it comes with a simulator to test.

Comment: Yes I had a look at the article. What stucked me was: "Objects positioned using fixed numbers like player.x = 64 and player.y = 64 will always be 64 points away from the top and left edges, but based on the device will be closer or further away from center." So if I put an object in a 160X240 point (Center of 320X480), will it be the center even on a 640X480 screen?

Comment: No, it will be not centered, as the article said it will be 160x240 from the top left side. But corona gives you some ways to help you. For example display.contentCenterX return the value of the center of the screen (x coordinate) for any screen you are using, so if you want to put an image in the center you can just use image.x = display.contentCenterX; image.y = display.contentCenterY

Comment: Ok, but what I want is the point to be at the center. This is only an example. I could have chosen 123X234 for example. Have a look at krs's answer. That's exactly what I want to do. But I just want to know if this can be achieved by adding some options to the config.lua, and not to multiply all my points to the scale factor